# Server Socket Doesn't Bind to Specified Port

Tags: linux, sockets, gcc

I am implementing a multi threaded echo server in gcc under linux. I bind the server socket to port number `3000`. Below is my code used for binding.

**EchoServer.c**

```
struct sockaddr_in sock_var;
int serverFileDiscriptor=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
sock_var.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0");
sock_var.sin_port=3000;
sock_var.sin_family=AF_INET;
bind(serverFileDiscriptor,(struct sockaddr*)&sock_var,sizeof(sock_var));
```

However I see that the server binds to port number `47115` as shown below.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:47115           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          79942      22843/./EchoServer
```

As per my understanding, only specifying port number as `0` will bind the socket to a random unused port. What could be the possible reason for this? The server is started as root user and I've confirmed port number `3000` is unused and available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem with my code. The server socket binds to port number `3000` after I change

```
sock_var.sin_port=3000;
```

to

```
sock_var.sin_port=htons(3000);
```

So, this issue has got something to do with the network byte order.

Comment: It has to do with the fact that `sockaddr_in.sin_port` is *specified* to be 'port in network byte order', *in the 'man' page.*

Comment: @EJP - Thanks for clarifiying.